# Sync files from Active Directory to Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-server-2008, active-directory

How can I sync files from Windows Server 2008 to a Linux box?

Windows Server can sync files to another active-directory box automatically. Can I do that with Linux too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup Samba on the linux server, to make a windows share.  You can then use robocopy (use the /mir option to mirror) the files between the two.  There are a ton of options with robocopy (which is built into server 2008) to control the number of threads (files copied at the same time) how often its run, what permissions to replicate, etc.

try running:

```
robocopy /?
```

on your windows server for a list of options.

Answer (score 1):

Linux can access Active Directory file shares via [cifs](http://linux-cifs.samba.org/), and you can keep the files in sync on your linux system via [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).